# Type of expression is ambiguos without more context

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
text.drawInRect(aRectangle, withFont: font, lineBreakMode: .UILineBreakModeTailTruncation, alignment: .Center)
```

I get the error in .UILineBreakModeTailTruncation... so how can i solve it???
I'm working with Xcode 7, swift 2

And im getting another error, which is:
'drawInRect(_:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:)' is unavailable.. how can i solve it??

Thanks..!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The enum value you are passing is incorrect, you should pass the value like:

```
text.drawInRect(aRectangle, withFont: font, lineBreakMode: .TailTruncation, alignment: .Center)
```

or

```
text.drawInRect(aRectangle, withFont: font, lineBreakMode: UILineBreakMode.TailTruncation, alignment: .Center)
```

---

#### **FYI**

The [UILineBreakMode is deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UILineBreakMode) (From iOS 6 onwards), you should use [NSLineBreakMode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSLineBreakMode) instead. So the above code changes to:

```
text.drawInRect(aRectangle, withFont: font, lineBreakMode: .ByTruncatingTail, alignment: .Center)
```

or

```
text.drawInRect(aRectangle, withFont: font, lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail, alignment: .Center)
```

Comment: UILineBreakMode is deprecated; use NSLineBreakMode instead (.ByTruncatingTail)

Comment: @JoshuaKaden: Was already updating the answer, thanks for posting the comment :)